# set application name in pyside

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyside

I created an Application using Qt Creator/Designer under Windows 8 and Qt 5

it starts as follow

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        #MainWindow.setApplicationName("Facturo-Pro") # this doesn't work
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icons/app.png'))
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 600))
        MainWindow.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.English, QtCore.QLocale.UnitedStates))
```

i want to set the application name which should be shown on the window title and task bar

i tried to use

```
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.setOrganizationName("Moose Soft")
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.setApplicationName("Facturo-Pro")
```

or

```
QtCore.QSettings("my app","my org")
```

but it didn't work, in task bar and window title i see "python"

i don't want to use `setWindowTitle()` because i want to use

```
    MainWindow.setWindowFilePath(self.currentFile)
```

so i will later just update the FilePath and when editing the it a "*" will be shown on the window title!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Qt5, you can set the [applicationDisplayName](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#applicationDisplayName-prop), which is separate from the main title-bar text.

To show the [modification state](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowModified-prop) in the title-bar, you would do this:

```
    QtWidget.qApp.setApplicationDisplayName('Test')
    ...
    window.setWindowFilePath('/path/to/file.txt')
    window.setWindowModified(True)
```

and the title-bar would look like this:  <kbd>**file.txt* - Test**</kbd>

Alternatively, you can get a little more control of the title-bar text by using a special placeholder when setting the [window title](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowTitle-prop):

```
    window.setWindowTitle('/path/to/file.txt[*]')
    window.setWindowModified(True)
```

and the title-bar would look like this:  <kbd>**/path/to/file.txt* - Test**</kbd>

**EDIT**:

If you're using Qt4, there will no be `applicationDisplayName`, so you could try this, instead:

```
    QtGui.qApp.setApplicationName('Test')
    ...
    window.setWindowTitle(
        '/path/to/file.txt[*] - %s' % QtGui.qApp.applicationName())
    window.setWindowModified(True)
```

and the title-bar should look like this:  <kbd>**/path/to/file.txt* - Test**</kbd>

Comment: i cant find this function in PySide 1.0.7

Comment: @IsaakWahb. Bah, sorry - I saw the qt5 tag on your question and overlooked you were using pyside (which has no support for qt5, yet). I've updated my answer with an alternative soultion - but you're using a very old version of pyside, so you might want to think about upgrading.

Comment: Good answer from the Python Qt master as usual ;-)

Comment: Does this also set the application name shown in the Windows Taskbar?

Comment: The `setApplicationDisplayName(...)` function exists but doesn't seem to set the application name in the menu bar or app switcher in macOS when run like `python foo.py`.  Likewise for `setApplicationName(...)`.  I'm using PySide2 / Qt5.

Comment: The same results as for @TaylorD.Edmiston with PySide6 on macOS Ventura 13.1 when run as `./app.py`.